# MapKit Tile Overlay broken in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mapkit, openstreetmap

I have this code to implement OSM in my app *over* default Apple one:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    MKTileOverlay *overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
    [self.mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];});
```

And:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKTileOverlay class]]) {
    return [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithTileOverlay:overlay];
}
else return nil;
}
```

In iOS 7 it was fine, but now it returns multiple times and the map is not loaded at all:

```
<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithData data parameter is nil
```

How can I fix it? I tried to refactor my code, so first chunk of code is now:

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchTiles = dispatch_queue_create("fetcher", NULL);
dispatch_async(fetchTiles, ^{
    NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    MKTileOverlay *overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];});});
```

But this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Is your map view delegate still set?

Comment: Sure. I didn't change this part

Comment: My app started doing the same thing.  It doesn't crash; just lots of these error messages for what seems to be every map tile rendered.

Comment: But still it doesn't render the contents

Comment: I would add a debug line to make sure 1) you are getting valid tile URLs and 2) the images coming back are valid. It sounds like the Core Graphics routines under the hood that are trying to draw your tiles are choking on the data coming in from OSM.

Comment: We have the same issue. All tiles coming back are valid. We even tested out just sending the data of a 256x256 png to the result(data, error) block. It still prints out the error message every time. iOS 8 only. Like others mentioned it breaks nothing, but extremely annoying.

Comment: Has anyone figured out a way to at least silence this warning?

Comment: I have no fixes for you, unfortunately. I'm switched from this project and had no chance to find the ways

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using looks good, except...

It seems odd that you are doing the add overlay in a block.  I just add on an action and it does not seem to hang the UI at all.

just do...

```
    NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    MKTileOverlay *overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
    [self.mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

Also, I submitted a bug to Apple and when they wanted a sample, my overlay would not show...until I set the delegate.  (Even though I was wired up in storyboard).  Apple closed my bug as a duplicate so they know about it.

```
mapView.delegate = self
```